# Relations between eth0, wlan0

Tags: networking

I have eth0 and wlan0 two connections. I just wonder whether they would interfere with each other or not? To be more specific, when I use wired and wireless methods to connect to the same router, I found that sometimes my internet connection is disconnected. So why does this happen? And how can I avoid it?

The output of the command `lspci | grep 'work\|net'` follows:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)  
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

Comment: What makes you think you only have one network card? If you can have both wired and wireless connections, you have at least two network cards. Please [edit] your post and i) add the output of `lspci | grep 'work\|net'` and ii) clarify what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Thank you. The output is like: 00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
So I think I have two network cards indeed. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I have modified my question.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to add extra information. Comments are easy to miss and hard to read. And please ask something specific. "what is the mechanism behind these" is really not very clear.

Comment: @winston: Which connection exactly was dropped? The wireless connection to the router, the wired connection to the router, or the WAN connection of the router to the general internet? If it's an intermittent issue I'd guess the latter. In any case, in practice there's little benefit in having a wireless connection in addition to the wired connection to the same router because home internet connection speeds rarely exceed that of an Ethernet connection with reasonable recent network adapter hardware.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I don't have internet connection indeed. I am not quite sure which connection was dropped, but I think it was the wired connection. I used a program to receive data from the LAN with wired connection and wireless connection at the same time, connecting to the same router. I also agree with you that it was not a good idea, but sometimes when I connected to router with a cable for better connectivity, I forgot to disable the wireless card. In this case, both of wired and wireless connection existed and seemed to interfered with each other.

Comment: If you want to debug this issue further please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) during the next disconnection and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. Make sure to save the diagnostic script *before* that happens. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In a typical (and Ubuntu's default) configuration the two network interfaces will not interfere, not even when they're connected to the “same” network (e. g. when the Ethernet connection goes to a router/switch that is also the access point associated with the wireless network adapter).

There are ways to *make* them interact in various useful (or not so useful) ways but it doesn't seem like you're looking for any of them.

Comment: But in this case, I found that the connection dropped seemingly periodically.